# How to fix my Indicator to show on All timeframes

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Here is part of my script, the issue I have is that I am unable to get my indicator to show on the 4 hr and Daily timeframes. It will show all the way down to the 1 min but once I get past 1hr it disappears. I feel it has to do with the close of the day (is_friday), but my indicator is actually based off the close of the 1hr candle and 4hr candle above or below my emas at the end of the trading week. I've tried to look for answers but I'm at a lost at this point. Also I wanted it to color the whole new week as it progresses but it just gives a colored line on that one candle.

```
// Check if it is Friday at close of day CST
is_friday = dayofweek == dayofweek.friday and hour(current_time) == 15 and minute(current_time) == 00

// Check if EMAs are not in order
emasNotInOrder_Up = ema_1_1h > ema_2_1h or ema_2_1h > ema_3_1h or ema_1_4h > ema_2_4h or ema_2_4h > ema_3_4h
emasNotInOrder_Down = ema_3_1h > ema_2_1h or ema_2_1h > ema_1_1h or ema_3_4h > ema_2_4h or ema_2_4h > ema_1_4h

// Check if the candles are above the EMAs on all timeframes
candles_above_emas1 = close > ema_1_1h or close > ema_2_1h or close > ema_3_1h or close > ema_1_4h or close > ema_2_4h or close > ema_3_4h
candles_below_emas2 = close < ema_1_1h or close < ema_2_1h or close < ema_3_1h or close < ema_1_4h or close < ema_2_4h or close < ema_3_4h


// Set the background color based on the EMA order, candles, and day/time
bgcolor(ema_order2 and candles_below_emas and is_friday ? color.rgb(251, 42, 42) : na, title="red Background")
bgcolor(ema_order and candles_above_emas and is_friday ? color.rgb(30, 145, 34, 56) : na, title="Green Background")
bgcolor(emasNotInOrder_Up and emasNotInOrder_Down and is_friday ? color.rgb(244, 197, 41, 18) : na, title="Yellow Background")
bgcolor(candles_above_emas1 and candles_below_emas2 and is_friday ? color.white : na, title="White Background")
```

Comment: the code can't be compiled without knowing what is in those `ema_*_*` variables